# Delete turned-off features in Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, disk-space

Windows 7 lets you enable or disable optional components with the "Turn Windows Features On and Off" dialog, but all components continue to be stored on the hard drive, just in case you decide you need them later.

While this might make perfect sense on computers with Tera-byte hard drives, I'm running Windows 7 as a dual boot OS installed on an SSD, and every MB counts. Is there any way I can delete the installers for my turned-off components and free up precious disk space?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not from an already installed Windows 7.

However, you can delete features you do not want from the installation media with [**vLite**](http://www.vlite.net/index.html) (it is originally made for Vista but has been updated for Windows 7).

[image]